# Student Booking Form

Tags: google-apps-script

Our spreadsheet only has 2 columns for data to match students with tutors. The first column is student information. The second has "yes" or "no" for availability with a tutor. We want it so that after students have been selected from the Google Form by a tutor, they are marked "NO" on the sheet and their information removed from the Form options. "YES" means the student is available.

```
function updateCHECKBOX() {
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const studentsSheet = ws.getSheetByName("Students")
const students =studentsSheet.getRange(2,1,studentsSheet.getLastRow(),1).getDisplayValues()

const studentsList = students.filter(row=>row[1]=="YES").map(row => row[0])

const form = FormApp.openById("1FvM3v3Cg1b2lSRTJpp3V_pl369wkJoAS7ypO0J4AhQg")
const studentsQuestion = form.getItemById ("2116012197")
studentsQuestion.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(studentsList)
}
```

However, when we run the final code, we get "Error, Exception: Array is empty: values". Images of the sheet and form are below:

["Students" sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVKQN.png)

[Google form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD8tX.png)

Comment: Your getRange is only getting 1 column so row[1] is undefined.

Comment: Thank you! We are not too experienced with coding, so could you specify how we can fix this in the code exactly? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

The getRange().getValues() above only gets column A (row[0]), but in your filter you are comparing with row[1] which means column B. Since the row arrays have only 1 value row[1] is undefined.

**Script**

```
function updateCHECKBOX() {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const studentsSheet = ws.getSheetByName("Students");
  // get values from row 2, column A to getLastRow()-1, column B
  const students =studentsSheet.getRange(2,1,studentsSheet.getLastRow()-1,2).getDisplayValues()

  const studentsList = students.filter(row=>row[1]=="YES").map(row => row[0])

  const form = FormApp.openById("1FvM3v3Cg1b2lSRTJpp3V_pl369wkJoAS7ypO0J4AhQg")
  const studentsQuestion = form.getItemById ("2116012197")
  studentsQuestion.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(studentsList)
}
```

**Test case**

In your case you have a 2 dimensional array but each row is only one value;

```
function test1() {
  try {
    var a = [[1],[2],[3]];
    console.log(a[1][0]);
    console.log(a[1][1]);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

11:42:26 AM Notice  Execution started
11:42:26 AM Info    2
11:42:26 AM Info    undefined
11:42:26 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

**References**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

Comment: Ok, but how do we put the code together? In other words, how do we implement the code under the "test case" section provided?

Comment: It's already been done in my script.  Just replace yours with mine.  The second script was only intended to show you how your original script was in error.

Comment: Oh, thank you! However, when we run your script we get the following error message: "Questions cannot have duplicate choice values. updateCHECKBOX @ StudentMatch.gs:29." Line 29 is the last line of the script.

Comment: Now your problem is in another script.   Which we haven't seen.

Comment: No I meant the last line of the script you sent "studentsQuestion.asMultipleChoiceItem" etc.

Comment: I fixed it! I added another filter. Thank you!